# sign in always returns null

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-signin

I am trying to enable to google sign-in in my app.
I have saved my app in 2 folders (Folder1 (personal) and Folder2 (work)).

In Folder1, it works perfectly fine.
I sign in using "**GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension**".
I check if I logged in with "**GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)**". It returns TRUE

```
public void requestGoogleFitPermission() {

        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this,
                GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                account,
                fitnessOptions);

        Boolean sign = isSignedIn();
        Log.v("signed in???", String.valueOf(sign));   //returns TRUE

    }


private boolean isSignedIn() {
        return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) != null;
    }
```

Now when I try the EXACT same thing in Folder2 it doesn't work correctly.
I get the sign-in pop up and I choose my account. 
But for some reason it doesn't retain the account. 
When I call "**GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)**" its always NULL.

```
public void requestGoogleFitPermission() {

        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                this,
                GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                account,
                fitnessOptions);

        Boolean sign = isSignedIn();
        Log.v("signed in???", String.valueOf(sign));   //returns FALSE

    }


private boolean isSignedIn() {
        return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) != null;
    }
```

I can see that in the working case the google account gets stored in "zzq.class"

[image]

but is null for the other folder

[image]

Why does this happen?? What should I check??
Scratching my head for hours on this. Any input is really appreciated.

Comment: Are they different projects?

Comment: yes. Can gradle settings affect GoogleSignIn??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it happens because in your firebase console you just have only one project, try to create a new project on firebase, link that new project (the one that is not assigned to the one you are using I'd say the one is in FOLDER2) and try it again, it should work.